# Updating a DIV while writing text into a textarea

Tags: jquery

I would like to "live" update a DIV in the page with the text the user enter in a textarea.
I have the following markup

```
<div id="previewNote" class="note yellow" style="left:25;top:25px;z-index:1;">
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="author"></div>
    <span class="data"></span>
</div>
```

and wrote this jQuery code

```
/* Listening for keyup events on fields of the "Add Note" form: */
$("[ID$=NoteText]").live('keyup', function(e) {
    if (!this.preview)
        this.preview = $("[ID$=previewNote]");

    /* Setting the text of the preview to the contents of the 
       input field, and stripping all the HTML tags: */
    this.preview.find(".body").html($(this).val().replace(/<[^>]+>/ig, ''));

});
```

But the div does not get updated. What do am I missing?

thanks!

**EDIT**
This is the form.

```
<form action="/Note/SaveOrDelete" id="crudForm" method="post"><input id="IssueNoteID" name="IssueNoteID" type="hidden" value="0">

<!-- The preview: -->
<div id="previewNote" class="note yellow" style="left:25;top:25px;z-index:1;">
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="author">admin</div>
    <span class="data"></span>
</div>

<div style="margin: 16px 0px 0px 180px; width: 240px;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
    <tbody><tr valign="top">
        <td colspan="2">
            <label for="NoteText">Testo</label>
            <br>
            <textarea cols="30" id="NoteText" name="NoteText" rows="6"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
            <label for="NoteDate">Data</label>
            <input id="noteDate" name="noteDate" style="width: 120px" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <div style="text-align:right;">
        <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Salva" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

but, listen, I have changed the jQuery code in

```
/* Listening for keyup events on fields of the "Add a note" form: */
$("[ID$=NoteText]").live('keyup', function(e) {
    /* Setting the text of the preview to the contents of the 
       input field, and stripping all the HTML tags: */
    $("[ID$=previewNote]").find(".body").html($(this).val().replace(/<[^>]+>/ig, ''));
});
```

and everything works!!! :O

It is very strange...

Comment: Can you provide the HTML for your "Add Note" form?

Comment: your code works for me using a <textarea id='NoteText'></textarea>

Comment: The code you supplied is working for me.  Can you include more of the code from your page?  Maybe something else is causing the issue. Also, make sure you put your live event inside of a "ready" event e.g. - $(function(){ <put live binding here> }); That will make sure the document is ready

Comment: Please have a look to my edit. I have found a solution but I dont understand anyway why the previous one does not worked... thanks a lot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using this HTML:

```
<textarea id="NoteText"></textarea>

<div id="previewNote" class="note yellow" style="left:25;top:25px;z-index:1;">
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="author"></div>
    <span class="data"></span>
</div>​​​
```

and this JS:

```
​jQuery(function($) {
    var input = $('#NoteText'),
        preview = $('#previewNote div.body');

    input.keyup(function(e) {
        preview.text(input.val());
    });
});​
```

...works fine for me, and no need to strip tags either.

#### EDIT

This also works fine for me:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#NoteText').live('keyup', function(e) {
        $('#previewNote div.body').text($(this).val());
    });
});​
```

Comment: Did you see my comment? It would be nice to discover why it works just without caching the element but interacting directly with it...

Comment: Appended some JS using `live` and without caching the elements. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not properly. I have changed the previous function simply removing this code "if (!this.preview) this.preview = $("[ID$=previewNote]");". You can check with my initial question and with the edit. Anyway now it's working. I was just curious to uinderstand why before not...

Comment: **[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** is removed in `jQuery 1.9 version` Use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="product_title" id="product_title" type="text">

<h4 class="title">Enter a Title Here</h4>
```

```
    $('#product_title').on('keyup', function(e) {
       $('.title').text($(this).val());
    });
```

this was my solution.