# jQuery : how turn link from textarea to image in div?

Tags: html, jquery

How can I turn the URL link from textarea to do image in `<div>` ?

Example:

```
<textarea id="sample">https://tvorbawebu.net/eshopserver/uploads/thumbnail/Pentair-Led-Pool-Lights.jpg</textarea>
<div class="viewimage"><img alt="" src="URLfromtextarea"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating a DIV while writing text into a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722283/updating-a-div-while-writing-text-into-a-textarea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.attr()` function to set the `src` and the `.text()` to get the url as follows:

```js
$( document ).ready( function(){
     let url = $('#sample').text();
     if(url)
          $('#myImg').attr('src', url);
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="sample">https://tvorbawebu.net/eshopserver/uploads/thumbnail/Pentair-Led-Pool-Lights.jpg</textarea>
<div class="viewimage"><img alt="" id="myImg" src=""></div>
```

Comment: Won't work using `text()` if user inserts that url text and it isn't preset on page load