# JS insert URL link from textarea to the image src with live preview

Tags: javascript, html

How can I insert URL text from textarea to the image src with this code:

```js
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('previewimage');

wpcomment.onmouseover = wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
    document.getElementById('prevCom').innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="previewimage" id="previewimage" placeholder="drag drop here"></textarea>

<div id="prevCom"><img alt="" id="nahled" src=""></div>
```

I already asked here: [jQuery : how turn link from textarea to image in div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63089018/jquery-how-turn-link-from-textarea-to-image-in-div)

but there is only jQuery solution with no live preview.

Comment: live preview of what and where?

Comment: live preview the image with url from textarea

Comment: You mean `document.getElementById('nahled').src= this.value.trim();`

Comment: mplungjan thank you so much :)

Comment: @HVHambardzumjan You are welcome. I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no need to capture keypress and mouse leave. besides by changing image attribute like below, or `image.setAttribute('src', this.value)`

```js
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('previewimage');
var image = document.getElementById('nahled');

wpcomment.onkeyup = function(){
  image.src = this.value;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="previewimage" id="previewimage" placeholder="drag drop here"></textarea>

<div id="prevCom">
  <img alt="" id="nahled" src="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('previewimage');

wpcomment.onmouseover = wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
    document.getElementById('nahled').src = this.value;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="previewimage" id="previewimage" placeholder="drag drop here"></textarea>

<div id="prevCom"><img alt="" id="nahled" src=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with test and eventListener

```js
const wpcomment = document.getElementById('previewimage');
const image = document.getElementById('nahled');

wpcomment.addEventListener("input", function() {
  const str = this.value.trim();
  if (str.startsWith("data:")) { // data uri
    image.src=str;
    return;
  }
  try {
    const url = new URL(str);
    // if (url.href.contains(....) ===-1) { /* test extension here */ }
    image.src=url.href;
  } catch (_) {
    console.log("Not a valid URL")
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
#prevCom img {
  height: 300px;
}
#prevCom img::before {
  content: "ッ";
}
```

```html
<textarea name="previewimage" id="previewimage" placeholder="drag drop here"></textarea>

<div id="prevCom">
  <img alt="" id="nahled" src="" />
</div>
```